# Database layout for data-driven ordering (task priority)

Tags: database

I am not sure how to layout my database.

I have a model named "Task" and the user is able to create as many tasks as they want and then after they created those tasks, they can just order (prioritize) them however they want.

I thought about creating a field (`task_number`) to order the elements (Tasks) by.
If the user wants `sample2` to be the first, the database would look like:

```
id     name       task_number
1      sample1    2
2      sample2    1
3      sample3    3
4      sample4    4
```

Is this a good method or how would one structure the database?

Comment: Very vague and not about Python and Django, but Database layout.

Comment: @handle, yeah right. I haven't even started creating my model. :( but anyway, thanks for reading...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in general it's a correct approach.

You may also want to consider replacing "task order" with "priority" (normal, high, low, etc.) as it may be far more user friendly and easier to maintain (creating new tasks will not require reordering).